# Complex SQL query based on adding the values of several columns

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a table called `music_lib` which has a bunch of columns and over 2000 entries.

```
id | track_id | total_plays | total_downloads | likes | active | etc | etc
```

I'm trying to select only the most recent 50 active entries, based on `id` but I want to order them relative to the combined values (all ints) of the following columns :

```
total_plays + total_downloads + likes
```

So basically I want the latest 50 entries ordered by how popular they are (popularity being based on the combined plays, downloads and likes of each entry).

But I have no idea how to formulate this query with PHP / MySQL (using wordpress)..

I know I can get the most recent 50 entries with the following but no idea how to order those results based on the combined figure of the three columns as mentioned above.

```
$getpodcasts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM music_lib WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50");
```

Comment: Track_id + x ??? What?

Comment: Sorry track_id should have been 'likes', my bad, will correct the question

Answer (score 1):

then use order by  and your calculation and then id like below-

```
$getpodcasts = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT * FROM music_lib 
    WHERE active = 1 
    ORDER BY (track_id + total_plays + total_downloads) DESC,
             id desc 
    LIMIT 50");
```

first it looks for  track_id + total_plays + total_downloads and sort them accordingly and then sort them by id

Comment: let me know whether it works for you or not... if helpful please accept as answer and upvote to

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this partially works. It shows only 50 in the correct order, but it is calculating the sum of the 3 columns from EVERY entry in the table, not JUST the last 50 which I am trying to do. Any ideas?

Comment: you can remove - limit 50

Comment: actually i could not understand your need ... thanks for your reply